# Finding continuity, differentiability and continuous differentiability for a function with variables $f(x)=x^\beta\sin(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}) $

Tags: calculus

> $$f(x)=\begin{cases}\begin{align}&x^\beta\sin(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}) & ,x\neq0 \\
> &0 & ,x=0\end{align}\end{cases} \\ (\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb N)$$
>
> Find for which $\alpha,\beta$ the function is 1.continuous 2. differentiable 3. continuously differentiable 4.differentiable twice at 0.
>
> A function $f$ is said to be continuously differentiable if the derivative $f'(x)$ exists, and is itself a continuous function.

Well I know that $x^\beta$ answers all of the above for all $\beta$ since it's an elemetary function its always continuous and always differentiable, but I know that $\sin(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}})$ although always contentious, will never be differentiable as x go to 0 for $\alpha\ge1$. (I don't suppose I can choose $-(\alpha\in\mathbb N)$ to make $\sin x^\alpha$ ?)

So the only way to make it differentiable is to choose $\alpha=0, \forall\beta$, for those two it will also be continuously differentiable and differentiable twice at 0.

I guess I'm not supposed to guess the alpha and beta but rigorously find them with the definitions...

Comment: Incomplete, seeing as $f(x) = x^2 \sin(1/x)$ is both continuous and differentiable. You have to work with the definition and see what relation between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you get.

Comment: @Fantini you mean the epsilon delta definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the definition of continuity, you must have the following: $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = f(0)$$

that is, $$lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^\beta \cdot \sin{\frac{1}{x^\alpha}} = 0$$
But that will always yield $0$, if $\beta > 0$, since the $x^\beta$ part goes to $0$ and $-1 \leq sin{\frac{1}{x^\alpha}} \leq 1$. (squeeze theorem!) If $\beta \leq 0$, the limit won't exist, because the $x^\beta$ part will go to infinity and the $\sin$ part alternates sign.
Now, to the differentiability. We say $f$ is differentiable at $x = 0$ if the following exists: $$lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h}\\ lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{h^\beta \cdot \sin{\frac{1}{h^\alpha}}}{h} \\ \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} h^{\beta - 1} \cdot \sin{\frac{1}{h^\alpha}}$$

that exists only if $\beta - 1 > 0$, i.e. $\beta > 1$, by the same argument before. There is no restriction on $\alpha$.

Comment: About alpha and beta being naturals, that means that they can't be negative isn't it ?