# Derivability and continuity of $x^p \sin(\frac{1}{x^q})$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ define as 
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x = 0$} \\
x^\gamma \sin(\frac{1}{x^\alpha}), & \text{if $x\neq 0$}
\end{cases}$$
For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z_+}$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$.

For wich values of $\alpha$, $\gamma$:

(i) $f$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

(ii) $f$ is derivable in $\mathbb{R}$.

(iii) $f'$ is continuous in $\mathbb{R}$.

(iv) $f$ is twice derivable in $\mathbb{R}$.

I can't see any constraints for any item (then they are all valid for those $\alpha, \ \gamma$ defined). But i'm not sure about that.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/620441/finding-continuity-differentiability-and-continuous-differentiability-for-a-fun?rq=1

Comment: How can i guarantee that, for example, $f$ is differentiable for the other points?

Comment: $f$ is infinitely differentiable at any point $\neq 0$, since it's obtained as the product and the multiplication of infinitely differentiable functions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For i) we get $$\left|x^{\gamma}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}\right)\right|\le |x|^{\gamma}$$ this tends to zero if $\gamma>0$